What is the most common notation to describe cyclostationary stochastic processes?
Can a cyclostationary stochastic process be described as:
$\{X_t[i]:i\in\mathbb{N}\}\quad\forall~t\in\{1,2, \dots,T\}$
where variability at the $t^\text{th}$ index across all repetitions/seasons follows a multivariate normal distribution:
$X_t\sim\mathcal{N}_K(\mu_t, \Sigma_t)$
with $\mu_t=E[X_t]\simeq\bar{x_t}$, $\bar{x_t}\in\mathbb{R}^K$
and $\Sigma_t=\operatorname{var}[X_t]$, $\Sigma_t\in\mathbb{R}^{K\times K}$,
estimated from past observations $x_t$ at index $t$ for all $K$ dimensions.
My main issue is related to how to handle the time index $t$, considering it is not relevant to the stochastic nature of the process; conversely, stochastic processes can be formulated with multiple variables as
$\{X(t,i):i\in\mathbb{N}\}$
but I'm still unsure as to the best way to represent $t$.
Additionally, some cyclostationarity references employ lower case letters for the underlying process (e.g. $x(t)$):
$E[x(t)] = E[x(t+T_0)]$

I see some notation adopted here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclostationary_process#Wide-sense_cyclostationarity

@Galen most of that notation is focused on autocorrelation analysis of cyclostationary processes, I'm mostly interested in briefly describing the stochastic nature of a process that I already know to be autocorrelated; moreover, using lower case to is confusing; I've updated my questions to note that.

I cannot make any sense of the initial notation, in part because when interpreted mathematically it is indeed nonsense and even with a generous reading doesn't seem to say anything.  Moreover, the following statements seem to suggest that $X_t$ and $X_i+kT$ are the same random variables (not just RVs with the same distributions) for all integral $k.$ There are two conclusions to draw: (1) make sure you define whatever notation you use and (2) make an effort to understand how your audience is likely to understand that notation in the context of other notation they commonly use.

@whuber the idea was to extend the generic notation for a stochastic process ${X(t):t\in T}$ to describe the cyclostationary process  as a collection of random variables indexed not by the time index $t$ (hence why it's not used as an argument) but the period/repetition $i$, as, per the formal definition, interleaved stochastic processes for each $t^\text{th}$ observation in the period.

That "generic notation" describes any sequence of objects.  But nothing you add to it later captures the idea of cyclostationarity.  Have you looked at, say, the Wikipedia article for ideas?

Doesn't $X_t\sim\mathcal{N}_K(\mu_t, \Sigma_t)$ entail that each $t^\text{th}$ observation follows the same distribution? To me that is in line with $E[x(t)] = E[x(t+T_0)]$ that I included (and linked to) in the question, taken precisely from that wikipedia article as a requirement for cyclostationarity.

No, it merely says that every $X_t$ has a Normal distribution.  It says nothing about the periodicity.

@whuber a normal distribution parametrized the same way (same mean $\bar{x}$, same variance $\Sigma_t$) hence why it's effectively the same distribution. Perhaps the issue here is objectively describing that $t$ is itself periodic (goes back to 1 after $T$ observations)

Yes, that's right.
